# Git push not appearing in Github

Tags: java, git, github, repository

I recently just made a few changes to my repository and committed and pushed everything as usual with no warnings or errors.

However, Github doesn't reflect these recent changes. When I look through the source files through Github's file view, all the files that I had changed look the same as before.

However, when I make a new clone of my repository and look through those files instead, they are all the most recent version with my committed updates.

How do I resolve this issue with github?

Comment: What is the output for `git remote -v`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem with a branch that I could not see on `github` it is actually due to the fact that `github` currently meets some issues as you can see here https://status.github.com/

Comment: This seems like a possibility. I'll wait a bit and check back later.

Comment: @WayWay yes probably